# Throw error "Input string was not in correct format" ? C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

I'm trying to read `.csv` file but it throwing error `input string was not in correct format`. Here is my `.csv` excel file screenshot [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPHXB.png)

Here is class

```
 class DowStock
{
    public string coName { get; set; }
    public double coPrice { get; set; }
    public double coChange { get; set; }
    public decimal coChangePct { get; set; } 
    public long coVolume { get; set; } 
    public decimal coYTDchange { get; set; } 
}
```

here is form code

```
 static DowStock SplitRow(string Row) { 
  DowStock rowResult = new DowStock(); 
  string[] splitRow = Row.Split(",".ToCharArray()); 
  rowResult.coName = splitRow[0]; 
  rowResult.coPrice = double.Parse(splitRow[1]); 
  rowResult.coChange = double.Parse(splitRow[2]); 
  rowResult.coChangePct = decimal.Parse(splitRow[3]); 
  rowResult.coVolume = long.Parse(splitRow[4]);
  rowResult.coYTDchange = decimal.Parse(splitRow[5]);
  return rowResult; 
}
```

Comment: `coVolume` is having `####`.Also `comma` and you are parsing it as `long`

Comment: You tried `Convert.ToString()` / `Convert.ToDouble()` ... already? Every Value in `splitRow` is correct?

Comment: can you tell me how can i resolve it .I'll place `###` with some values no problem and what is best data type for `,` between numbers?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? Which line is causing the error? What is the value of `splitRow[index]` (whatever element it is) at the time the exception is raised? This is basic problem solving information, and you should learn to solve this sort of issue yourself. You should also learn to search here and at Google for the error message you're seeing before posting; I see 10 similar questions in the **Related** list over there ----->>>>> that would have been shown to you when posting. Did you read those (and the others here) to see if they helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see that some of the columns were having `####` which are not convertible to Double values and that causing the exception, Best option to handle such situation is `TryParse` which will give you the minimum or default value of that particular type if the conversion is failed. So I would like to suggest you to use `double.TryParse`, `Int64.TryParse` and `decimal.TryParse` for conversion.

For example: Lets consider `rowResult.coPrice = double.Parse(splitRow[1]);` for obtaining this value we can use like the following:

```
double coPrice = 0.0;
double.TryParse(splitRow[1], out coPrice);
rowResult.coPrice = coPrice;
// The value will be 0.0 if the input is not convertible or
// else it will be populated with the required value
```

Like this you can escape from the `FormatException`

Comment: Thanks for response,if i use `double.TryParse` then its giving me error `double does not contain defination for try parse`

Comment: I have updated my answer with sample snippet could you please take a look

Comment: i have correct both `double` columns but now its giving me error on `decimal` .What about `decimal`?

Comment: You can try `decimal.TryParse` as well

Comment: hi..Now its showing data in `gridview`.thanks but why `0` in mostly columns? [LINK](https://i.imgsafe.org/a4b5d85264.png)

Comment: excel `.csv` file [LINK](https://i.imgsafe.org/a4ca44baf4.png) and code [LINK](https://i.imgsafe.org/a4cd561049.png)

Comment: @HameedKhan: `0` because they were not convertible to the required type

Comment: Hope that `%` creating issues for you in conversion, remove `%` before passing that value to the Tryparse